# Emitting in Vue.js and Vuetify returns error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've got two components. One parent, and one child component. In the child component I'm using a Vuetify Button component. When a user clicks the button, it should emit from the child to the parent component.

I've tried using different Vue methods to emit and capture the emit.

These are the components I'm using. I'm working with "Single file components".

```
// customer.vue | Parent component

<template>
    <v-container grid-list-xl fluid>
        <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-dialog 
                persistent max-width="600px">
                    <customer-messages @cancelmessage="handleCancelMessage"></customer-messages>
            </v-dialog>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import CustomerMessages from "@/views/customer-care/customer-care_customer-messages.vue"

export default {
    components: {
        CustomerMessages,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            methods: {
                handleCancelMessage() {
                    console.log('emit worked!');
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

```
// customer-care_customer-messages.vue | Child component

<template>      
    <v-btn 
        color="blue darken-1" 
        flat 
        @click="cancelMessage">
        Cancel
    </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {

        };
    },
    methods: {
        cancelMessage() {
            this.$emit('cancelmessage');
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

I expect the parent component to log "emit worked!". Instead, I keep getting the following error message:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "cancelmessage": got undefined

found in

---> <CustomerMessages> at src/views/customer-care/customer-care_customer-messages.vue
       <ThemeProvider>
         <VDialog>
           <VCard>
             <Customer> at src/views/customer-care/customer.vue
               <VContent>
                 <VApp>
                   <App> at src/app.vue
                     <Root>
```

Comment: Your error message shows `cancelmessage`. However, in your code, the method is `cancelMessage`. It should be something wrong with the capital `M`.

Comment: Maybe put `methods` outside of `data`?

Comment: @Traxo, thank you! That fixed the issue :) Overlooked that one..

Comment: @bcjohn cancelMessage is the method in which I executed the emit("cancelmessage")   :)